# Raw data for Central Limit Theorem

Tags: data-request

I want to show my students how Central Limit Theorem works in the **real word** examples.

More precisely, I want them to plot histograms and make Kolmogorov–Smirnov using SPSS.

I have already prepared artificial data using VBA. However, I would also like to do test on **real data**.

The data I wish to posses are:

- IQ scores
- noise in signal

I spend good amount of time browsing Google and open data sites, but I didn't found nothing useful.

> **Request**: Can you help me with finding such data?
>
> **Side question**: Do you have some tips for how should I browse for such data?